# Can WiX installer upload files to ftp

Tags: ftp, wix

I'm trying to determine if the WiX installer framework can include a step to upload files to an FTP server. Is there a reference in the documentation to that?

Comment: Do you want to upload files from within your MSI at installation time to a FTP site (not a good idea), or do you want to upload the compiled MSI from your development system to an FTP server when you build your setup?

Comment: I'd like to build an installer that uploads to a websites ftp server to automate deployment of the web app to a shared hosting provider.